# Ethernet stopped working after running some commands

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet, ethernet

I was trying to share my internet connection with my ethernet wire.
It didn't work.

But now I cannot get internet with ethernet.

I executed this command:

```
sudo ifconfig enp2s0f1 169.254.82.80
```

The result of ifconfig is this:

```
enp2s0f1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:56:dc:80:9a:3e  
          inet addr:169.254.64.195  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e56:dcff:fe80:9a3e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:126 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:8640 (8.6 KB)

enp2s0f1:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:56:dc:80:9a:3e  
          inet addr:169.254.8.45  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:644032 (644.0 KB)  TX bytes:644032 (644.0 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:a5:89:50:f5:0d  
          inet addr:100.64.194.17  Bcast:100.64.223.255  Mask:255.255.224.0
          inet6 addr: 2001:67c:1220:c190:cc59:999:f43f:c2d5/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::82a5:89ff:fe50:f50d/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:67c:1220:c190:82a5:89ff:fe50:f50d/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1280  Metric:1
          RX packets:58488 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15426 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:19185577 (19.1 MB)  TX bytes:2154035 (2.1 MB)
```

What did I do and how is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

169.254.82.80 is a non routable IP windows assigns when it can't get any other IP. It's pretty much useless.
And you assigned that useless IP 169.254.82.80 to your enp2s0f1 interface. This assignment is not persistent so things would go back as before after a reboot. Or (assuming you connect to internet via your wireless) just shut down and bring up the interface `sudo ifdown enp2s0f1 && sudo ifup enp2s0f1`